# angular 4 re-binding when model stays the same after ngModelChange

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an input

```
<input [(ngModel)]="plot" type="number" step="0.01" (ngModelChange)="onPlotChange($event)" />

onPlotChange(value) {
    this.plot = value;
    this.plot = Math.round(this.plot * 100) / 100;
}
```

When i enter a number, lets say - 1.956, it instantly changes to 1.96 as it is rounded up, this.plot is different to the value is rebound to the view.

When i enter - 1.951, it stays like that in the view because the model value before the change was 1.95 and after the change it is 1.95 so it doesn't detect any changes and doesn't re-bind the value back to the view so the view stays with .1951.

How do i force angular to re-bind the value to the view?

http://plnkr.co/kJxF7rixZXQdWRMnVoRd
Enter 0.956 - expected result 0.96
Enter 0.951 - expected result 0.95, actual result in view 0.951

Comment: Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: it changes the model, pilot's value is actually correct, but then the focus is left on the text, and the user simply keeps typing cause nothing is stopping him - if you type 0.956 it changes to 0.96 but user can still continue to type - again, nothing is stopping him.

Comment: When typing 0.956 you cant keep typing as it changes to 0.96 as you type @Stavm

Comment: ngModelChange shouldn't fire because of re-draw from a model change @Chrillewoodz

Comment: you are correct this is indeed very interesting. [this also happens with setter getter](http://plnkr.co/edit/oxZy4VAhjQR0BLV7VxH8?p=preview)

Comment: @J.D. Correct, but it is a 2-way binding and the view side is not in sync with the model side because of this behavior, the best way to deal with this is to let angular know within the ngModelChange callbak that the view needs to be updated (just like in WPFs PropertyChanged)

Comment: It is not in sync as in the view it displays "0.191" and in the model it is "0.19" the fact that it is a problematic situation doesn't change the fact that the 2-way binding are not synced. of course this is because we override the onModelChange, but along with the override we should be able to let angular know if it needs to refresh the view even if the model wasn't changed. this is one of the issues of 2-way binding engines and why I prefer react over angular.

Comment: I didn't talk about if the code is sync or async, 2 way binding should be aligned, in this instance the model and the view are not aligned, no matter the reason, the framework needs to give you the tools to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is an alternate solution to achieve the desired result. You can use angular's (keyup) event**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="plot" type="number" step="0.01" (keyup)="onPlotChange(plot)" />

    onPlotChange(value) {
      this.plot=value;
        this.plot = Math.round(this.plot * 100) / 100;

}
```

Comment: Why do keyup works but ngModelChange doesn't? they both fire, they both don't really change the model.

Comment: Your solution causes 2 round trips between the component.ts and the view, but it works so I'll take it. this is still a very strange behavior.